# How to Broadcast to a shutdown system using java?

Tags: java, sockets

We use socket.send(packet) function in java to send a "packet" to a given port.
My problem is that i have to send a packet to a shutdown system using UDP protocol.
The problem with send() function is that first it verifies whether the host IP is 
multicast or not. Now my local area network is of broadcast type. So i am having 
problem is using this function.
can anyone please give me a way ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how send udp packets in java?

First of all, broadcasting must be enabled in your network.

Then, all your servers must join to agreed multicast address.

```
InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName( "230.0.0.1" );
MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket( 12345 );
socket.joinGroup( address );
```

When you want to activate the system shutdown, send an agreed message (for example, "die") to the multicast address.

```
DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
socket.receive( packet );
String received = new String( packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength() );
```

The servers when accept that message should initiate a shutdown flow.

Comment: I am sorry to say but i think you have not got my problem clearly.
see..i am making wake on lan.
so i dont have to shut down the system but to wake up.
now the problem is that...send() function works only in multicast.
and my local area network is of broadcast type.
so this send() function doesn't work.

Comment: First of all, broadcast has nothing to do with it. *Multicasting* must be enabled in your network *routers*, *if you have any*. Secondly the OP isn't doing multicasting at all so the answer is irrelevant.